# How to automatically sync json (or any data file like csv) to GitHub

Tags: python, github, automation, scripting

I Have a charting program I wrote in python using Dash-Plotly and published to Heroku (which automatically deploys when there are new changes in the GitHub). To keep the data updated I have to run a script that I wrote daily that downloads the data, which is about 4000 json files. It takes a little while, and then I have publish to GitHub, and the rest is taken care of from the automatic deployment via Heroku. My question is how to I automate this process so that the json files are downloaded nightly (from the cloud as my computer will not be on) and then automatically sync the GitHub repo with the new data sets. I just want to be able to open my app on Heroku and know that the charts are pulling from the latest available data and not have to do this every day. Currently I am using VSCode on Linux.

Comment: Constantly changing data doesn't belong in your repository.  Store it elsewhere (e.g., a cloud bucket) and download it as part of your deployment process or build it into a deployment artifact.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the direction! What I did was rewrite the data download script to also upload the data to a google cloud storage bucket, then hosted the script on a google cloud compute engine and set up the cronjob to run daily. Then I reworked the app to pull the data from the cloud bucket as needed to plot the charts. Now the data is always updated, and I only need to deploy to github when there are changes in the app itself now.